# How can i add additional textInput in react native prompt?

Tags: react-native

```
<Prompt
title="Say something"
placeholder="Start typing"
defaultValue="Hello"
visible={ this.state.promptVisible }
onCancel={ () => this.setState({
    promptVisible: false,
    message: "You cancelled"
}) }
onSubmit={ (value) => this.setState({
    promptVisible: false,
    message: `You said "${value}"`
}) }/>
```

I'm using cross platform component react-native-prompt in my react native code. I don't know how to add an extra input text in the code below.

Comment: Looking through the code it doesn't seem like you can. Of course you can simply start your own branch and add `{this.props.children}` and then you'll be able to insert your own component in the `<Prompt></Promp>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not feasible what I did but I had changed the node_module file of react-native-prompt. I changed the prompt.js file in that i have passed extra props with an additional TextInput in it.

this is what my prompt.js file looks like

**Prompt.js**

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import {
  Modal,
  Platform,
  Text,
  TextInput,
  TouchableWithoutFeedback,
  View
} from 'react-native';
import styles from './styles';

export default class Prompt extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    title: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    visible: PropTypes.bool,
    defaultValue: PropTypes.string,
    placeholder: PropTypes.string,
    defaultValueSecond: PropTypes.string,
    placeholderSecond: PropTypes.string,
    onCancel: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    cancelText: PropTypes.string,
    onSubmit: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    submitText: PropTypes.string,
    onChangeText: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    borderColor: PropTypes.string,
    promptStyle: PropTypes.object,
    titleStyle: PropTypes.object,
    buttonStyle: PropTypes.object,
    buttonTextStyle: PropTypes.object,
    submitButtonStyle: PropTypes.object,
    submitButtonTextStyle: PropTypes.object,
    cancelButtonStyle: PropTypes.object,
    cancelButtonTextStyle: PropTypes.object,
    inputStyle: PropTypes.object,
    textInputProps: PropTypes.object,
  };

  static defaultProps = {
    visible: false,
    defaultValue: '',
    defaultValueSecond:'',
    cancelText: 'Cancel',
    submitText: 'OK',
    borderColor:'#ccc',
    promptStyle: {},
    titleStyle: {},
    buttonStyle: {},
    buttonTextStyle: {},
    submitButtonStyle: {},
    submitButtonTextStyle: {},
    cancelButtonStyle: {},
    cancelButtonTextStyle: {},
    inputStyle: {},
    onChangeText: () => {},
  };

  state = {
    value: '',
    valueSecond: '',
    visible: false,
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({value: this.props.defaultValue,valueSecond:this.props.defaultValueSecond});
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    const { visible, defaultValue,defaultValueSecond } = nextProps;
    this.setState({ visible, value:defaultValue,valueSecond:defaultValueSecond });
  }

  _onChangeText = (value) => {
    this.setState({ value });
    this.props.onChangeText(value);
  }

  _onChangeTextSecond=(valueSecond)=>{
    this.setState({ valueSecond });
    this.props.onChangeText(valueSecond);
  }

  _onSubmitPress = () => {
    const { value,valueSecond } = this.state;
    this.props.onSubmit(value,valueSecond);
  };

  _onCancelPress = () => {
    this.props.onCancel();
  };

  close = () => {
    this.setState({visible: false});
  };

  _renderDialog = () => {
    const {
      title,
      placeholder,
      placeholderSecond,
      defaultValue,
      defaultValueSecond,
      cancelText,
      submitText,
      borderColor,
      promptStyle,
      titleStyle,
      buttonStyle,
      buttonTextStyle,
      submitButtonStyle,
      submitButtonTextStyle,
      cancelButtonStyle,
      cancelButtonTextStyle,
      inputStyle
    } = this.props;
    return (
      <View style={styles.dialog} key="prompt">
        <View style={styles.dialogOverlay}/>
        <View style={[styles.dialogContent, { borderColor }, promptStyle]}>
          <View style={[styles.dialogTitle, { borderColor }]}>
            <Text style={[styles.dialogTitleText, titleStyle]}>
              { title }
            </Text>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.dialogBody}>
            <TextInput
              style={[styles.dialogInput, inputStyle]}
              defaultValue={defaultValue}
              onChangeText={this._onChangeText}
              placeholder={placeholder}
              autoFocus={true}
              underlineColorAndroid="white"
              {...this.props.textInputProps} />
              <TextInput
              style={[styles.dialogInput, inputStyle]}
              defaultValue={defaultValueSecond}
              onChangeText={this._onChangeTextSecond}
              placeholder={placeholderSecond}
              autoFocus={true}
              underlineColorAndroid="white"
              {...this.props.textInputProps} />
          </View>
          <View style={[styles.dialogFooter, { borderColor }]}>
            <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={this._onCancelPress}>
              <View style={[styles.dialogAction, buttonStyle, cancelButtonStyle]}>
                <Text style={[styles.dialogActionText, buttonTextStyle, cancelButtonTextStyle]}>
                  {cancelText}
                </Text>
              </View>
            </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
            <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={this._onSubmitPress}>
              <View style={[styles.dialogAction, buttonStyle, submitButtonStyle]}>
                <Text style={[styles.dialogActionText, buttonTextStyle, submitButtonTextStyle]}>
                  {submitText}
                </Text>
              </View>
            </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Modal onRequestClose={() => this.close()} transparent={true} visible={this.props.visible}>
        {this._renderDialog()}
      </Modal>
    );
  }
};
```

Then this is how I used that prompt in my react-native class file.

**App.js**

```
<Prompt
          title={"UPDATE DETAILS ID:" + this.state.default_srk_id}
          placeholder="Enter Username"
          defaultValue={this.state.default_user_name}
          placeholderSecond="Enter Password"
          defaultValueSecond={this.state.default_password}
          visible={this.state.promptVisible}
          onCancel={() => this.setState({
            promptVisible: false,
            message: "You cancelled"
          })
          }
          onSubmit={(value, valueSecond) => {
            this.setState({ promptVisible: false,username: value, password: valueSecond})
          }}
        />
```

Though I have found another solution of this requirement is **Model** for custom pop-up but this is how we can use react-native-prompt for multiple TextInput.